# Algorithm on trajectory analysis

Tags: algorithm

I would like to analyse trajectory data based on given templates. 
I need to stack similar trajectories together.
The data is a set of coordinates (xy, xy, xy) and the templates are again lines defined by the set of control points.

I don't know to what direction to go, maybe to Neural Networks or pattern recognition?

Could you please recommend a page, book or library to start with?

Kind regards,
Arman.

*PS:
Is it the right place to ask the question?*
**EDIT**
To be more precise the trajectory contains about 50-100 control points.
Here you can see the example of trajectories:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFE0JLx6L-o

Comment: It might be the right place.  Your description seems a bit vague to me.  What are these trajectory data, what are templates supposed to represent, what significance do the control points have?

Comment: @Svante: thanks for response. Actually the trajectory is a 3d points: xyz, xyz.. etc.. The templates are calculated from the model: http://195.221.212.246:4780/arm2arm/DATA/orb.png 
The model trajectory I can generate as much as possible. But for the real data points I have about 50-100.

Comment: Do you want to match similar trajectories or trajectories with a similar motion pattern irrespective of rotation?, scale?, translation?

Comment: @tom10: As a first approximation I would like to see the type like: circle, boxy, triangular, elongated ellipses open trajectory. Here as an example for the precalculated templates: http://picasaweb.google.de/arm2arm/Orbits#5463330309129834482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a clustering algorithm to 'stack the similar trajectories together'. I have used  [spectral clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering#Spectral_clustering) on trajectories with good results. Depending on your application [hierarchical clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) may be more apropriate.

A critical part of your analysis will be the distance measure between trajectories. State of the art is [dynamic time warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping). I've also seen good results achieved with a modified [Hausdorff measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure).

Comment: @Michael Ulm:  thanks Michel, the distance measure is the most unclear part for me. The rest can be done with clustering algorithms as you mentioned: I usually use MST or DBSCAN.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a quite vague.

You can use regression analysis (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) to find the relationship between x and y on a set of coordinates, and then compare that with other of trajectories.

Are there always four coordinates per trajectory? You might want to calculate the euclidian distance between the first coordinates of all trajectories, and then the same for the second and so on.

You might want to normalize the distance and analyze the change in direction instead. It all comes down to what you really need.

If you need to stack similar trajectories together you might be interested in the k-nearest neighbour algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm). As for the dimensions to use for that algorithm, you might use your xy coordinates or any derivates.

Comment: @bitc:The trajectories defined well up to 100 points. I can interpolate them to continues function.Thanks for mentioning KNN. I will try the idea on Mahanalobis distance with weighted K-NN.